# python, selecting a textbox with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to enter some text into a textarea with selenium.

Inspection of the source reveals the following about the textareas code.. my text should be entered where it says "Text goes here":

```
<iframe id="tinymcewindow_ifr" frameborder="2" src="javascript:""" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text AreaPress ALT-F12 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help" style="width: 90%; height: 90px; display: block;">

    #document
        <!DOCTYPE >
        <html>
            <head xmlns="http://www.site.org/xhtml"> … </head>
            <body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " contenteditable="true" onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('tinymcewindow').onLoad.dispatch();" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr">
                <p> … </p>
            </body>
        </html>

</iframe>
```

When I try and select the textarea with some command like:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("tinymce")
```

it returns an error message like this;

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 293, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 681, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 164, in execute
   ...
```

the command:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("tinymce")
```

Gives this error message:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 197, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 681, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 164, in execute
 ...
```

How does one select a textbox like this with Selenium?

Comment: isn't you content inside an iframe?

Comment: @javo, yes it's. I have updated the question with the iframe section.. sry everyone, didnt think that was of importance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
driver.find_element_by_id("tinymce")
```

Elements in [HTML Forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) have name attribute, that is what you tried to match with `find_element_by_name`.

If you have a form like

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

You could match the input for first name with `find_element_by_name('firstname')`, but that's not what you want to do right now.

The element you want to select looks like this

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " contenteditable="true" onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('tinymcewindow').onLoad.dispatch();" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr">
```

So you can

1. `find_element_by_id("tinymce")`
2. `find_element_by_css_selector("#tinymce")`
3. `find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tinymce']")`
4. ...

... and for the sake of completeness ...

Once you have selected this element, you can fill it with

`driver.find_element_by_id("tinymce").send_keys("Hello world")`

EDIT:

Sometimes people don't realise that selecting an element works within the context of current page. If your content is inside an iframe, you need to switch to this iframe first.

`driver.switch_to_frame("frameName")`

Then you can go back with `driver.switch_to_default_content()`

See [Selenium Python - Navigating](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html)

Comment: @user3053161 I've updated my answer, I think you might have problems with iframes - and please **think** about a selector you use for `switch_to_frame`, don't just update your question with another stacktrace